# Analytic solutions to a nonlinear second order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following 2nd order PDE analytically, but haven't succeeded so far. I have tried to separate the variables, but it doesn't work here. I would be very grateful for any suggestions that could lead me in the right direction in solving it and for all suggestions about where I could look further. The equation is the following:
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=- \frac{b(x)}{2} (1-u(x,t))^2+\frac{b(x)}{c} \frac{ \partial^2 u(x,t)} {\partial x \partial t},$$
where 
$u(x,t)$ is the unknown function, 
$b(x)$ is a known function of $x$ only, and
$c$ is a constant.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you even know it has a solution? The vast majority of nonlinear PDE do not...

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=- \frac{b(x)}{2} (1-u(x,t))^2+\frac{b(x)}{c} \frac{ \partial^2 u(x,t)} {\partial x \partial t},$$
Let $u(x,t)=v(x,t)-1$
$$\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}=- \frac{b(x)}{2} v(x,t)^2+\frac{b(x)}{c} \frac{ \partial^2 v(x,t)} {\partial x \partial t},$$
Change of variable : $X(x)=\int{b(x)}{dx}$

$b(x)dx=dX$

Let $V(X(x),t)=v(x,t)$
$$\frac{\partial V(X,t)}{\partial X}=- \frac{1}{2} V(X,t)^2+\frac{1}{c} \frac{ \partial^2 V(X,t)} {\partial X \partial t},$$
Change of variable : $T(t)=ct$

Let $W(X,T(t))=V(X,t)$
$$\frac{\partial W(X,T)}{\partial X}=- \frac{1}{2} W(X,T)^2+ \frac{ \partial^2 W(X,T)} {\partial X \partial T},$$
Now, there is no parameter (constant nor variable) in the PDE, which is a major simplification.

Answer (score -2):

$1$ is the solution of the partial differential equation.

Comment: $1$ is _a_ solution to the ODE. But it is certainly not the general solution.